# Asp.Net Core при билде проекта в папку bin не копируются dll nuget пакетов

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Visual Studio 2017
При бидле проекта к впвку ./bin не копируются dll depenedency библиотек

[имеется в виду](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vchcm.png)

[у библиотек нет "Copy Local"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MuekN.png)

Comment: Если я не ошибаюсь, то все нужные DLL собираются только после публикации приложения. То есть Вам нужно ПКМ по проекту - Публикация - далее выбираем что и как (можно в папку, можно FTP, можно Azure), далее там, куда указали будет полный проект.

Comment: Вы правы. при публикации собирается весь проект. Вопрос в том как работать  с проектом в процессе разработки. Каждый раз делать publish - это даже не смешно.

Comment: А зачем Вам пакеты в папке при разработке?  Я понимаю там файл базы, картинки или еще что подобное, но пакеты, которыми идет управление через NuGet... Зачем?

Comment: Не, ну если вам так хочется работать с пакетами, то изначально они в `%UserProfile%\.nuget\packages`

Comment: Зачем работать с внешними библиотеками из папки проекта? Странный вопрос. Могу походя накидать с 10 задач, но для примера текущая. Есть приложение https://github.com/RSuter/NSwag генерирующее .ts код на основании контоллеров (.dll файл проекта web), но для работы требует дополнительный набор библиотек. Библиотеки приатачены к проекту, но при билде не добавляются в папку проекта. Т.е. по вашему мнению нужно каждый раз делать паблиш перед генерацией .ts файлов?

Comment: В Core - все библиотеки, которые установлены с помощью "поставщиков" пакетов (таких как NuGet) - устанавливаются и используются из директории, что я дал вам выше (это вы можете посмотреть даже в консоли отладки). В папке проекта, до публикации находятся только .dll самого проекта, а так же! все .dll, которые были добавлены вручную. Пакеты из NuGet вы не увидите в  папке ./bin. Я не знаю, можете попробовать добавить пакет вручную (Добавить ссылку-обзор... выбрать .dll файл), тогда он будет в нужной директории.